# lsass.exe constantly using about 25% of CPU

Tags: cpu, virus, anti-virus, malware, lsass

Recently noticed that my computer was running a bit slow and saw that a program which I have never seen before, lsass.exe is using about 25% of my cpu nearly all of the time. If I close it I receive an error message and am told the computer will reboot in 1 minute. I then scanned my computer with ESET and found no viruses. I then scanned with Malwarebytes and discovered 1 infiltration, which I let it clean. I then rebooted and found that the number of scvhost.exe's that had been previously running had decreased by one. The lsass.exe was still consistently using 25% of my CPU and a new program called TrustedInstaller.exe used a large amount of CPU on bootup and then diminished to 0% CPU.

How can I fix this?

P.S. I am unsure because of the limited amount of time before logoff but when I kill it the issue seems to go away.

If you claim that it is a legitimate process can you please explain why I have never seen it before and why, even though I am constantly in task manager, it has never been shown to use this much CPU...

Edit - two instances of csrss.exe are now running. One can be opened from system 32 while when clicking the show file location option on the other nothing appears

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited it. Sorry I'm just a bit anxious...

Comment: Just for your information, showing that you've done research and having trouble at a particular point in an issue is considered good among the Q&A community. It encourages others to answer your question, as well as creating quality content which is beneficial for stackexchange and more importantly for all of its users, us. I recommend you read [help center](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm afraid there's no private space to talk. Why not use comments?

Comment: I just need some additional help and didn't want to spam the page. Right off the bat I cannot navigate to the Active Directory Diagnostics.

Comment: @Clark - I have no idea what that is and I know pretty much every tool out there.  The process in question of course is legitimate.  The first step boot into a minimal configuration and see what happens.  You can use `msconfig` to do this.

Comment: @Clark Turns out, the first link is for something different than Windows 7/8, and thus irrelevant. However, give [this thread](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140264-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-caused-by-apps/) a try. They stated that constant usage of CPU is associated with a faulty diver.

Comment: Ok, booted into minimal mode and two csrss.exe's started up. One can be seen simply by starting task manager while the other requires me to hit show processes from all users and then I can see both of them running. The lsass.exe issue still occurs while in minimal boot mode. Thank you Varaquilex for the response I will do this and comment back here.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the following applications:

1. AdwCleaner
2. Malwarebytes
3. OTL(OldTimer's List-It)

After you have done that, run each of them separately.
Post logs here.